# QFileDialog output as Parameter in function

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2

I'm trying to figure out how to pass a QFileDialog as a parameter to a function. Right now i have a function which requires 6 predetermined parameters in order to run:

```
self.ui.btn_convert.clicked.connect(lambda: convert.pfx_to_pem(file_path1+filename.extension, 
                                                               password_to_file_path_1, 
                                                               folderpath1+filename.extension, 
                                                               folderpath2+filename.extension, 
                                                               folderpath3+filename.extension, 
                                                              folderpath4+filename.extension))
```

What i initially have done is created 2 functions, one for getting the filename of a file and one that gets the folder name like such:

```
def browse_pfx(self):

    file_filter = 'PFX-fil (*.pfx)'
    file_path = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', r'C:/', file_filter)
    self.ui.lineedit_pfx.setText(file_path[0])

def browse_folder(self):
    folder_path = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self)
    self.ui.lineedit_mapp.setText(folder_path)
```

These i initiade with 2 buttons:

```
self.ui.btn_select_pfx.clicked.connect(lambda: self.browse_pfx())
self.ui.btn_select_map.clicked.connect(lambda: self.browse_folder())
```

What I'm wondering is how i should structure

Is there anyway to pass the output of browse_folder and append a filename to the pfx_to_pem function as an parameter?

As well as the browse_pfx, could you pass the return value of the function as an parameter to another function?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm still trying to figure out how your application works.

You have 3 buttons: `btn_convert`, `btn_select_pfx` and `btn_map_pfx`.

1. When you click on `btn_select_pfx`, you're selecting a single `file_path` to be the main target of `convert.pfx_to_pem`.
2. When you click on `btn_map_pfx`, you're adding a new `folderpath` to the function `convert.pfx_to_pem`.
3. When you click on  `btn_convert`, you call `convert.pfx_to_pem` with the set parameters.

If that's not the case, correct me later on the comments.

One way of doing what you want, is to restructure how things are done in `convert.pfx_to_pem`. If you need dynamic paramters, with the ability to append / remove items before the function gets executed, you could use a list object.

Create a list on your main class, for example, and pass that list to `convert.pfx_to_pem`:

```
# Create the new parameters on your class
self.filepaths = [""]
self.folders = []

# Connect the convert.pfx_to_pem to the btn_convert
ext = filename.extension
secret = password_to_file_path_1
func = lambda: convert.pfx_to_pem(self.filepaths, ext, secret, self.folders)
self.ui.btn_convert.clicked.connect(func)

def browse_pfx(self):
    file_filter = 'PFX-fil (*.pfx)'
    file_path = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', r'C:/', file_filter)
    self.ui.lineedit_pfx.setText(file_path[0])

    # Overwrite the dynamic file path
    self.filepaths[0] = file_path

def browse_folder(self):
    folder_path = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self)
    self.ui.lineedit_mapp.setText(folder_path)
    self.folders.append(folder_path)

    # Append a new folder to the convert.pfx_to_pem paramter
    self.folders.append(folder_path)

# Note that you do not need to use lambdas here.
# self will be included on browse_pfx and browse_folder automatically
# by python
self.ui.btn_select_pfx.clicked.connect(self.browse_pfx)
self.ui.btn_select_map.clicked.connect(self.browse_folder)

# Next time when convert.pfx_to_pem is called, it will use the data stored inside
# each list given that you adapted the script the new parameters.
```

One other way you can do it, is to pass the class instance's reference to the `convert.pfx_to_pem` lambda. This way, you can access the entire class attributes and methods inside `convert.pfx_to_pem`, including the newly created lists `self.filepaths` and `self.folders`.

Answer (score 0):

I went on the same task later that night and found a solution using the evil global variables. It seemed to do it, however it's not pretty.

But heres the updated code:

```
def browse_pfx(self, lineedit_pfx):
    file_filter = 'PFX-fil (*.pfx)'
    global file_path
    file_path, _filter = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open ", "C:/", "PFX-fil (*.pfx)")
    lineedit_pfx.setText(file_path)

    global pfx_file
    pfx_file = file_path

def browse_folder(self, lineedit_mapp):
    folder_path = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self)
    lineedit_mapp.setText(folder_path)

    global dir_path
    dir_path = folder_path
    filename_suffix_crt = 'crt'
    filename_suffix_key = 'key'
    filename_suffix_pwd = 'txt'
    #filename_suffix_p12 = 'pfx'

    user_cert = 'user_cert'
    pem_ca = 'ca_cert'
    private_key = 'private_key'
    encrypted_key = 'new_encrypted_key'
    new_pw = 'new_Pwd'
    new_p12 = os.path.basename(file_path)

    global user_cert_path
    global pem_ca_path
    global private_key_path
    global encrypted_key_path
    global new_pwd_path
    global p12_path

    user_cert_path = os.path.join(dir_path, '.'.join((user_cert, filename_suffix_crt)))
    pem_ca_path = os.path.join(dir_path, '.'.join((pem_ca, filename_suffix_crt)))
    private_key_path = os.path.join(dir_path, '.'.join((private_key, filename_suffix_key)))
    encrypted_key_path = os.path.join(dir_path, '.'.join((encrypted_key, filename_suffix_key)))
    new_pwd_path = os.path.join(dir_path, '.'.join((new_pw, filename_suffix_pwd)))
    p12_path = os.path.join(dir_path, 'new_' + new_p12)
```

So i passed the dir_path and pfx_file to the function.
And for the LineEdit input password i ended up changing the function to:

```
def pfx_to_pem(self, pfx_path, pkey_path, pem_path, pem_ca_path, encrypted_key_path, new_pw, dir_path, lineedit):

global pfx_password  
        pfx_password = lineedit.text()
```

And then i called the function sending the lineedit as a parameter to the function.
So pretty much i have a QFileDialog that prints the path to a file onto a LineEdit.
Then i set the LineEdits text inside the function.

```
self.ui.btn_convert_2.clicked.connect(
            lambda: Convert_OEC_Elite.pfx_to_pem(self, pfx_file, private_key_path, user_cert_path, pem_ca_path,
                                       encrypted_key_path, new_pwd_path, dir_path, self.ui.lineedit_password_2))
```

This is however as i said, not as much of a pretty solution, especially using globals the way i did. I haven't been working with python for more than a month hence the mess in my code.